# Trying to create profile to profile recommendations in a Django(DRF) project with TFRS (tensorflow recommenders)

Tags: tensorflow, django-rest-framework

I am creating a DRF project, which allows users to register, sign in and interact with each other. In this project, users are allowed multiple profiles, as a way to show different faces of themselves (for example, you may be a software developer and a carpenter. This project's specification is to allow you to have individual profiles for each).

this is my Profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
SEX_MALE = 'M'
SEX_FEMALE = 'F'
SEX_NON_BINARY = 'N'
SEX_OTHER = 'O'
SEX_CHOICES = [
    (SEX_MALE, 'Male'),
    (SEX_FEMALE, 'Female'),
    (SEX_NON_BINARY, 'Non-Binary'),
    (SEX_OTHER, 'Other'),
]

user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX_CHOICES)
# current_role = models.CharField(max_length=180)
current_role = models.ForeignKey(JobCategory, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='current_role')
experience = models.PositiveIntegerField()
professional_interests = models.TextField()
bio = models.TextField()
profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='econx/images', blank=True, null=True)
default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
skills_i_need = models.ManyToManyField(JobCategory, related_name='skills_i_need')
skills_to_offer = models.ManyToManyField(JobCategory, related_name='skills_to_offer')
calendar_link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Another feature of this application is to provide recommendations on profiles, to see which profiles you might find of interest (just to clarify, the recommendations are profile to profile).
The fields in the Profile model that I want to provide recommendation on are:

- current_role
- title
- skills_i_need
- skills_to_offer

I am providing recommendations on these fields, as the data is somewhat standardized.

I am attempting to generate the recommendations using TFRS (Tensorflow Recommenders), however, i have very limited knowledge in this space. In my recommendation file, i keep getting this error:

```
Detected at node PyFunc defined at (most recent call last):
unsupported object type int
     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[retrieval/streaming/ReduceDataset]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1874]
```

I have exhausted everything i understand and can understand from the documentation, making sure my data pipeline looks okay, my model should be taking in the type of input it does, logging and etc.

here is my recommendation file (excuse all the debugging lines)

```
ProfileModel = apps.get_model(settings.PROFILE_MODEL)
profiles = ProfileModel.objects.all()

source_profile_ids = []
target_profile_ids = []

for profile in profiles:
    for skill_needed in profile.skills_i_need.all():
        profiles_offering_skill = ProfileModel.objects.filter(skills_to_offer__in=[skill_needed]).exclude(user=profile.user)
        for offering_profile in profiles_offering_skill:
            source_profile_ids.append(str(profile.id))
            target_profile_ids.append(str(offering_profile.id))

    similar_job_profiles = ProfileModel.objects.filter(current_role=profile.current_role).exclude(user=profile.user)
    for similar_profile in similar_job_profiles:
        source_profile_ids.append(str(profile.id))
        target_profile_ids.append(str(similar_profile.id))


# source_profile_ids = [str(id) for id in source_profile_ids]
# target_profile_ids = [str(id) for id in target_profile_ids]

# for id in source_profile_ids:
#     print(type(id), ' : ', id)

# for id in target_profile_ids:
#     print(type(id), ' : ', id)

source_profile_ids = [id for id in source_profile_ids if id]
target_profile_ids = [id for id in target_profile_ids if id]


interactions = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({
    'source_profile_id': source_profile_ids,
    'target_profile_id': target_profile_ids
})

source_profile_ids_vocabulary = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(mask_token=None)
target_profile_ids_vocabulary = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(mask_token=None)

source_profile_ids_vocabulary.adapt(interactions.map(lambda x: x['source_profile_id']))
target_profile_ids_vocabulary.adapt(interactions.map(lambda x: x['target_profile_id']))

print("Source profile vocabulary size:", source_profile_ids_vocabulary.vocabulary_size())
print("Target profile vocabulary size:", target_profile_ids_vocabulary.vocabulary_size())


target_profile_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    target_profile_ids_vocabulary,
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(target_profile_ids_vocabulary.vocabulary_size(), 64)
])

source_profile_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    source_profile_ids_vocabulary,
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(source_profile_ids_vocabulary.vocabulary_size(), 64)
])



sample_ids = np.array(['1', '2', '3'])

# Use the model on some data
print("Target Profile Embeddings:", target_profile_model.predict(sample_ids))
print("Source Profile Embeddings:", source_profile_model.predict(sample_ids))

# Now you can print the model summaries
print(target_profile_model.summary())
print(source_profile_model.summary())



def process_profile_id(x):
    # Ensure the input is a tensor
    id_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(x['id'], dtype=tf.string)

    # Debugging: Print the shape and type of id_tensor
    print("Shape of id_tensor:", tf.shape(id_tensor))
    print("Type of id_tensor:", type(id_tensor))

    # Ensure the input is in the correct shape
    processed_id = tf.reshape(id_tensor, [1])
    return target_profile_model(processed_id)

profile_dicts = list(profiles.values('id'))

# Convert list to TensorFlow dataset
profile_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: iter(profile_dicts), 
    output_types={'id': tf.string}
)

profile_dataset = profile_dataset.batch(128).map(process_profile_id)

# Define the task
task = tfrs.tasks.Retrieval(metrics=tfrs.metrics.FactorizedTopK(
    profile_dataset
))

class ProfileRecommendationModel(tfrs.Model):
    def __init__(self, source_profile_model: tf.keras.Model, task: tfrs.tasks.Retrieval):
        super().__init__()
        self.source_profile_model = source_profile_model
        self.task = task

    def compute_loss(self, features: Dict[str, tf.Tensor], training=False) -> tf.Tensor:
        # Convert features to tensors
        source_profile_id_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(features['source_profile_id'], dtype=tf.string)
        target_profile_id_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(features['target_profile_id'], dtype=tf.string)

        # Debugging: Print the types of tensors
        print("Type of source_profile_id_tensor:", type(source_profile_id_tensor))
        print("Type of target_profile_id_tensor:", type(target_profile_id_tensor))

        # Compute embeddings
        source_profile_embeddings = self.source_profile_model(source_profile_id_tensor)
        target_profile_embeddings = target_profile_model(target_profile_id_tensor)

        # Compute loss
        return self.task(source_profile_embeddings, target_profile_embeddings)

model = ProfileRecommendationModel(source_profile_model, task)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(0.5))

# Train the model
# Adjust the batch size and epochs according to your dataset
logger.info('calling model.fit()')
model.fit(interactions.batch(4096), epochs=3)
logger.info('Recieved the response')

# Set up retrieval using the trained model
# Here, we use the source_profile_model for retrieval
index = tfrs.layers.factorized_top_k.BruteForce(model.source_profile_model)
index.index_from_dataset(
    profile_dataset.map(lambda x: (x['id'], model.target_profile_model(x['id']))))

# Get recommendations for a specific profile
# Replace 'some_profile_id' with the actual profile ID you want recommendations for
_, recommended_profile_ids = index(np.array(["some_profile_id"]))
print(f"Top 3 recommendations for profile 'some_profile_id': {recommended_profile_ids[0, :3]}")
```

I do not know if this is excessive, but I am also providing the stack trace for potentially useful information

```
2023-11-26 15:00:42.855322: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
Falling back to TensorFlow client; we recommended you install the Cloud TPU client directly with pip install cloud-tpu-client.
Creating converter from 7 to 5
Creating converter from 5 to 7
Creating converter from 7 to 5
Creating converter from 5 to 7
From C:\Users\lucap\Econx\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py:2976: The name tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy instead.

2023-11-26 15:00:48.511786: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
From C:\Users\lucap\Econx\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend.py:873: The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.

From C:\Users\lucap\Econx\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\tf_utils.py:492: The name tf.ragged.RaggedTensorValue is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.ragged.RaggedTensorValue instead.

Source profile vocabulary size: 13
Target profile vocabulary size: 12
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 84ms/step
Target Profile Embeddings: [[ 0.02176386  0.00125583  0.02401812  0.02040208 -0.01574477  0.02969709
  -0.01709174  0.01652541  0.01939433 -0.01534519 -0.04577042  0.0196485
   0.03953027 -0.00123714 -0.00792533 -0.00610024 -0.00464817  0.00826347
  -0.04910089 -0.00737684 -0.03821605 -0.0150045   0.03046194 -0.02843758
   0.01538659 -0.03342491 -0.0021381  -0.02845874  0.04722227  0.03998436
  -0.00707227  0.00678191  0.02767416  0.02251813 -0.02188896  0.01844275
  -0.02836763  0.04082293 -0.02311561 -0.0230091  -0.00451391 -0.02133939
  -0.02948312  0.01973429 -0.04695886  0.03107354  0.02770117  0.01831781
  -0.00153947  0.03506667  0.03070731  0.03661952 -0.01903541  0.04506418
  -0.0176497   0.02162737 -0.01784098  0.00985923  0.03236402 -0.02113049
  -0.02927628  0.044627   -0.00519395 -0.03344721]
 [-0.00482113 -0.04408371  0.0296103  -0.01821161 -0.03460415  0.03824775
  -0.03349094  0.0387508  -0.00779108 -0.00081009 -0.03139376  0.02388189
  -0.00325672  0.01709748 -0.02587469  0.04876142  0.04597205  0.03370187
  -0.02457449 -0.0337983  -0.01980748  0.02429637  0.02142407 -0.02570627
  -0.02258766  0.00980028 -0.00981909  0.02207761 -0.00734339  0.00652914
  -0.02200456  0.00020822  0.00531089  0.03405037  0.03766492 -0.04389336
  -0.04821406 -0.00074581 -0.03570393 -0.0262431   0.01711489 -0.00216921
  -0.03258981  0.04192353 -0.04220053 -0.01023583  0.0445067  -0.00130947
   0.02947073  0.04387157 -0.04578108 -0.04915937 -0.04012823 -0.02648776
  -0.03491948 -0.00175773  0.01402414  0.02235813  0.03048629 -0.03665642
  -0.04247514  0.0408553   0.04235272  0.00232451]
 [-0.03926639  0.03039857 -0.04388599 -0.03349812  0.03283603 -0.03876152
  -0.00817136  0.02786732 -0.03693651 -0.0334113  -0.00043994  0.0096065
  -0.0451057  -0.04846507 -0.03082362  0.02354128 -0.01613463 -0.01895442
   0.03571314 -0.04995867  0.03688384 -0.0495962   0.00239844 -0.01807382
  -0.01829394  0.00953569 -0.03318688  0.04849459  0.03662965 -0.04817326
  -0.01229843 -0.00144582  0.000776    0.0421637  -0.03324325 -0.02822276
  -0.03112258 -0.0315237  -0.00713937 -0.03267049  0.00655327  0.04557116
  -0.01777441  0.00354748  0.0283598  -0.02322419  0.00039238 -0.04372526
   0.02086643  0.04250911 -0.04599526 -0.04721915  0.03339871 -0.03413117
   0.03823396 -0.03926069 -0.01517683 -0.00965692  0.01187892 -0.00153559
   0.00640305 -0.02021538  0.01614029  0.01242678]]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 63ms/step
Source Profile Embeddings: [[ 1.99697502e-02 -1.07727535e-02  4.50144149e-02 -1.48898363e-03
   1.07482783e-02  8.95656273e-03 -3.11371442e-02  1.31290667e-02
   6.69016689e-03 -1.32671371e-02  2.25404613e-02  1.20251253e-03
  -3.55490930e-02  4.30377759e-02 -1.87920090e-02  4.74720635e-02
  -1.09472871e-02  1.95264928e-02  2.98220851e-02 -4.20833118e-02
   4.00546230e-02 -4.73666303e-02 -1.98944341e-02 -2.41100788e-03
  -4.17441241e-02  1.80446021e-02 -7.56070763e-03 -1.69240609e-02
  -8.87348503e-03 -2.10928321e-02  9.01247188e-03  3.31574343e-02
  -1.92026254e-02 -1.96760893e-03 -1.62267201e-02  3.32151912e-02
   1.61572210e-02 -2.79378295e-02  2.93363966e-02 -1.00778341e-02
  -3.26680318e-02  2.46471651e-02  2.93955691e-02  3.72729339e-02
   1.82956792e-02  3.86598371e-02  5.46710566e-03  4.55541536e-03
   2.30358578e-02 -1.95796378e-02 -1.76193342e-02  8.77721235e-03
   3.70300896e-02 -9.57245752e-03  3.69980000e-02 -2.17954163e-02
   2.05419548e-02  2.99007334e-02 -3.24903131e-02 -2.49487162e-03
  -2.49577649e-02 -2.98163779e-02  2.73158886e-02  3.05490531e-02]
 [-1.05948672e-02  8.26854631e-03 -4.88293767e-02  4.90958802e-02
  -3.18548232e-02 -4.90419045e-02 -1.90083627e-02  4.95021231e-02
   3.51152904e-02 -8.82228464e-03  8.61948729e-03  3.56110968e-02
  -1.00718848e-02  3.54543589e-02  2.90251039e-02 -3.46121937e-03
  -1.20139718e-02 -1.34151354e-02  3.93364318e-02  4.66880091e-02
   4.08226363e-02  3.16171907e-02 -2.94589531e-02  2.21951641e-02
  -2.34425664e-02 -4.49383520e-02 -4.21829112e-02 -3.08717974e-02
   3.48798297e-02  2.94449069e-02  4.20269854e-02  4.40062322e-02
  -3.20389122e-03  4.18052711e-02  1.37921609e-02  1.87935568e-02
  -1.78203732e-03 -3.25586349e-02  3.80089022e-02  2.45725997e-02
  -4.28186916e-02  2.60229371e-02  4.28957865e-03  8.36152956e-03
   3.15278433e-02 -2.16273069e-02 -1.05556846e-02  2.01897062e-02
   3.34613584e-02 -4.06785123e-02  3.80279534e-02 -4.39519770e-02
   4.28838246e-02  1.25100352e-02  2.61543505e-02 -3.32609564e-03
   2.94567607e-02 -7.46549293e-03  4.34394218e-02 -3.65588441e-02
  -4.28637154e-02  4.74047549e-02 -3.27520594e-02 -4.09566052e-02]
 [ 1.06024034e-02 -1.28030404e-02  2.57846154e-02  4.11105417e-02
   1.73781253e-02  2.55552270e-02 -3.21631059e-02 -1.39735229e-02
  -3.17742825e-02  4.37826551e-02 -4.18259390e-02 -4.87299450e-02
  -4.24455181e-02 -3.93934622e-02 -1.13895051e-02  4.14617173e-02
  -1.80516131e-02  4.81059216e-02 -3.13704610e-02  1.16208196e-02
  -4.06400785e-02  3.10404561e-02 -3.28036435e-02  1.98468901e-02
   2.24692263e-02  1.55456401e-02  3.23737152e-02 -3.47389355e-02
   3.26542519e-02 -1.86813995e-03 -4.72679026e-02  4.28791307e-02
  -1.80227868e-02  2.34446041e-02  2.64707953e-03 -3.81588936e-03
   3.87218110e-02  9.58926976e-05  2.69313119e-02 -2.92502176e-02
  -1.53384432e-02  4.03400995e-02 -4.76370454e-02  3.48246098e-03
  -3.79719846e-02  1.51168220e-02 -3.06346174e-02  2.18107216e-02
   4.28847708e-02 -4.98138666e-02 -2.03059074e-02  8.44696909e-03
   4.73573692e-02  1.82575099e-02  2.58891471e-02  1.08424053e-02
  -2.72717960e-02 -1.42944232e-02 -9.56609100e-03 -2.47886907e-02
  -4.67475653e-02 -1.92628857e-02 -3.82106379e-03  3.13453712e-02]]
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 string_lookup_1 (StringLoo  (None,)                   0
 kup)

 embedding (Embedding)       (None, 64)                768

=================================================================
Total params: 768 (3.00 KB)
Trainable params: 768 (3.00 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________
None
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 string_lookup (StringLooku  (None,)                   0
 p)

 embedding_1 (Embedding)     (None, 64)                832

=================================================================
Total params: 832 (3.25 KB)
Trainable params: 832 (3.25 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________
None
Shape of id_tensor: Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int32)
Type of id_tensor: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.SymbolicTensor'>
calling model.fit()
Epoch 1/3
Type of source_profile_id_tensor: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.SymbolicTensor'>
Type of target_profile_id_tensor: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.SymbolicTensor'>
Type of source_profile_id_tensor: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.SymbolicTensor'>
Type of target_profile_id_tensor: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.SymbolicTensor'>
2023-11-26 15:00:50.744510: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INTERNAL: Unsupported object type int
2023-11-26 15:00:50.744845: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INTERNAL: Unsupported object type int
2023-11-26 15:00:50.745266: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INTERNAL: Unsupported object type int
2023-11-26 15:00:50.745529: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INTERNAL: Unsupported object type int
2023-11-26 15:00:50.745711: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INTERNAL: Unsupported object type int
2023-11-26 15:00:50.745880: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INTERNAL: Unsupported object type int
2023-11-26 15:00:50.746056: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INTERNAL: Unsupported object type int
2023-11-26 15:00:50.746249: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INTERNAL: Unsupported object type int
2023-11-26 15:00:50.746427: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INTERNAL: Unsupported object type int
2023-11-26 15:00:50.746637: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INTERNAL: Unsupported object type int
2023-11-26 15:00:50.746833: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INTERNAL: Unsupported object type int
2023-11-26 15:00:50.746999: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INTERNAL: Unsupported object type int
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lucap\Econx\backend\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\lucap\Econx\backend\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\lucap\Econx\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\lucap\Econx\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\lucap\Econx\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\lucap\Econx\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\lucap\Econx\backend\recommendation\management\commands\profile_to_profile_recommendations.py", line 152, in handle
    model.fit(interactions.batch(4096), epochs=3)
  File "C:\Users\lucap\Econx\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\lucap\Econx\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 53, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node PyFunc defined at (most recent call last):
<stack traces unavailable>
Unsupported object type int
         [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
         [[retrieval/streaming/ReduceDataset]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1874]
```

Any kind of help, pointers or anything would be hugely appreicated! Thank you